Collectively snapping multiple selected objects, so their relative positions stay the same
If you have multiple objects selected (meshes, vertices, e.t.c.), and you use the 'Snap To' menu (shift+s), and choose one of the 'selection to ...' options, the effect is the same as selecting each object individually and applying that snap option, ex. selecting multiple cubes and then choosing 'selection to cursor' snaps each cube to the cursor, so they all have the same position:

results in:

All 3 cubes are now in the same position.
Is there a way to snap multiple objects collectively, such that their positions relative to each other remain the same, but the transform pivot point is what gets snapped instead? Ex. If the transform pivot point is set to active element, and I do the same snapping operation as above, the result would look like this:

I had to move the cubes manually for the example, but you can see that the relative positioning of the cubes is the same, but now the transform pivot point (in this case the active element) is snapped to the cursor.
Most of the time I just use workarounds to achieve this type of result when I need it (turning on snapping, parenting, e.t.c.), but they aren't always practical, and either way I wanted to check to see if there was some simple way of achieving this effect that I've been overlooking. Thanks.
